# HashMap observer Java which is going to detect the insert

Tags: java, hashmap, observer-pattern

Could somebody help me in creating a program which is going to observe a hashmap for any put's or add's and return the added key(value) once any item is put into it.
Once the observer detects the put , i get the response to one more method where i will perform some processing on the response object.

I am looking forward into suggestions over Observer in JAVA.

Comment: You could use a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to add the code which allows for observers. Alternatively employ some AOP library which does the decorating for you (although I'd suspect using those might be a little out of scope for now).

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at JavaFX properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm

In your case, using a `ObservableMap` would be well suited. This is a decorator, which allows tracking changes in a map: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableMap.html

So in your case:

```
// yourMap is the map that has to be observed
ObservableMap<Key, Value> observableMap = FXCollections.observableMap(yourMap);
```

Then you can attach a listener to `observableMap`.

```
observableMap.addListener(new MapChangeListener<SensorType, Node>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Key, ? extends Value> change)
            {
                // your code here
            }
        });
```

Or, using lambda's:

```
observableMap.addListener(
(MapChangeListener.Change<? extends Key, ? extends Value> change) ->
                {
                    // your code here
                });
```

Key and Value are placeholders, they should be they key and value type of your own map.